# what is wrong in this code that made for validating a input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a input where the user should write ELIMINA so the modal could be submitted, so far I writed this functionality for validation :

```
var validation = false;
    function validateElimina(e) {
        var inputField = e.target.value;
        if (inputField === 'ELIMINA') {
            validation = true;
        } 
        validation = false;
    }

    function onValidate() {
        if(validation == true) {
            return console.log('EXISTS')
        }
        return console.log('FALSE');
    }
```

this is input field :

```
{props.eliminaInput ? <Input onChange ={(e) => validateElimina(e) } className="elimina-input" type="text" autoFocus={true} /> : null}
```

and this is the button for submitting :

```
<Button
   onClick={() => onValidate()}
   className="button-modal col-5 py-2 text-uppercase">
    {props.buttonText}
</Button>
```

So for now, if I'm pressing the button doesn't matter what is in input field, it's showing FALSE. Help please.

Comment: You go into the if,,.... you set validation to true, you exit the if and set validation to false....

Comment: have a look on controlled components. create a state and set it’s value to onchange. then use the if else conditions onvalidate function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState()
function validateElimina(e) {
    const inputField = e.target.value;
   setInputValue(inputField)
}


function onValidate() {
        if(inputValue == “ELIMINA”) {
            return console.log('EXISTS')
        }
        else
        return console.log('FALSE');
    }
```

Comment: don’t forget to import useState

Answer (score 1):

You are always setting it to false. Move it before the if.

```
validation = false;
if (inputField === 'ELIMINA') {
  validation = true;
}
```

or use an else

```
if (inputField === 'ELIMINA') {
  validation = true;
} else {
  validation = false;
}
```

Comment: Validation is a global var, I can't use it in onValidate if it's in another function. Or I can, but I don't know how to do that. That's why I was thinking to set that as a global var and then change it in validateElimina function.

Comment: Oh wait I'm stupid, I see what you're saying, it worked. Thank you very much.